# Deshabilitar solo algunas fechas en DatePickerDialog

Tags: java, android, datepicker

estoy tratando de deshabilitar solo algunas fechas futuras en un `DatePickerDialog` he estado investigando un poco al respecto y parece que con `setSelectedDays` me debería de funcionar pero setSelectedDays no parece ser reconocido en mi código:

```
final Calendar c= Calendar.getInstance();
        dia=c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        mes=c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        anio=c.get(Calendar.YEAR);

        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getContext(), (view1, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth) -> fechaET.setText(dayOfMonth+"/"+(monthOfYear+1)+"/"+year)
                ,anio,mes,dia);
        datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(c.getTimeInMillis());
        datePickerDialog.show();
```

Por el momento el calendario que muestro solo he logrado deshabilitar las fechas anteriores con `datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(c.getTimeInMillis());` pero ahora necesito deshabilitas SOLO algunas fechas futuras del calendario por ejemplo el calendario tendrá disponibles las fechas 15, 16, 20, 31 de noviembre pero las demás estarán deshabilitadas para su selección. Espero me puedan ayudar de antemano muchas gracias!